# Adding certain parenthesis of a total sum in a single cell in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need assistance with the following please:
In one cell, I have an addition of: `((0)+(0)+(10))+((13)+(0)+(0))+((0)+(0)+(10))`.
I would like to only add the addition of the third parenthesis from every outer parenthesis so the total would give me 20.
Do you guys have any suggestion for this approach.

Comment: When you say you have an addition of `((0)+(0)+(10))+((13)+(0)+(0))+((0)+(0)+(10))`. Is this a formula? If yes, what is it? In the addition you give, the parenthesis have no effect, the sum of all the numbers will always be 33. It would help to know what you've tried so far. Can you also explain in more detail what it is you are trying to achieve? Please do so by [editing you question](https://superuser.com/posts/1405392/edit) and not in comments

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: He wants the sum of the 3rd of each group of 3, which would make 10+0+10=20.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA macro as a solution.

For excel formulas, using Find() and Mid() for multiple targets can get very long and convoluted.  Also there is difficulty here as the additive length changes.  0 is one digit and others are two digits.

This macro uses the active cell and adds each third element regardless of parenthesis.  The last line is commented out but can be used to insert your sum into your worksheet.

```
Sub sumSplit()
    Dim currCell As String
    Dim sums As Variant
    Dim myTot As Long
    Dim myIndex As Long
    Dim myString As String
    Dim myExit As Boolean

    myString = Replace(ActiveCell.Value2, "(", "")
    myString = Replace(myString, ")", "")
    sums = Split(myString, "+")
    myIndex = 2
    myTot = 0
    myExit = True
    Do While myExit
        If myIndex <= UBound(sums, 1) Then
            myTot = myTot + sums(myIndex)
        Else
            myExit = False
        End If
        myIndex = myIndex + 3
    Loop

    MsgBox myTot
    'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = myTot

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`=LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(","|",4))),FIND(")",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(","|",4))))-1) +
LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(","|",8))),FIND(")",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(","|",8))))-1) +
LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(","|",12))),FIND(")",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"(","|",12))))-1)`

**Caveats -** *This will work if:*

- in each set of outer parentheses, there are always exactly three sets of inner parentheses as shown in the example `((...)...(...)...(...))`
- the third inner parenthese contains a number and not an expression which evaluates to a number; spaces are ok `(  2 )`
- there are exactly three sets of outer parenthesis `((1)+(11)+(111))+((2)+(22)+(222))+((3)+(33)+(333))`

If the reference cell contains a formula then bracket every cell reference with FORMULATEXT `FORMULATEXT(A2)`. If it is sometimes a formula and sometimes text use `IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(A2),A2)`.

**EDIT:**
This improvement removes the third *Caveat*, namely, now there can be zero to 1000 outer parenthesised triplets (edit both `1000`s to the same value of whatever limit is needed).

`=SUM( IFERROR( NUMBERVALUE( LEFT( RIGHT( A2, LEN(A2) - FIND( "|", SUBSTITUTE( A2, "(", "|",  ROW($A$1:$A$1000)*4))),
      FIND( ")", RIGHT( A2, LEN(A2) - FIND( "|", SUBSTITUTE( A2, "(", "|", ROW($A$1:$A$1000)*4)))) - 1)), 0))`

**This improvement is an array formula so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it.**

Comment: I like the substitution of the 4th instance of something here. (8th, 12th...)

Comment: Yes you could remove the caveat for exactly three sets of outer parentheses by enclosing each line in `IFERROR(...,0) starting with the three lines already provided and continue to copy paste edit (the number from the series 4, 8, 12, 16... appears in two places on each line) until the you satisfy the requirements or the formula length is maxed out (whichever comes first!).